# Azure application gateway restrict by source IP and server name

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

We have an Azure Appgw running fronting several different backend web servers in what used to be a "named virtual host setup".

We want to restrict the access to one virtual named host by request IP.

I know you can have a firewall entry as Network Security Group on the AppGW virtualnetwork/subnet.

But this is a simple layer 3 filter, no option to select the HTTP host name in the filter rule.

Any options other than setting up another AppGW?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you will not be able to restrict traffic by client IP and HTTP headers using Application gateway as of now. You can only be able to restrict client by using NSG.

I would suggest Azure Frontdoor, which is might fit in your requirement.

Here is the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-application-security

Regards, 
Msrini

Comment: this looks like it is for web applications, meaning Azure Web app, which is a different thing. The Appgw is fronting docker backend web servers.

Comment: Do you have docket as the backend for application gateway? You ask cannot be achieved by Application Gateway currently. Blocking/ restriction of IP address based on request IP is not supported.